# Having bootstrap css and prime ng css files in the same application?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, primeng

I am planning on using bootstrap on my main dashboard page and Prime NG data tables on a page that will show up from one of the menu options on my dashboard. I am using angular (angular 4) .

1. Would it be an issue if I reference the bootstrap css file and also prime ng theme css files?
2. I am planning to import the bootstrap css file as 
   @import url ('path to bootstrap css file') inside the style.css file  and within my specifyc component css file I plan to import the prime NG theme css file

I am not expert with styling and CSS just wanted to confirm if the above is a good approach and would there be issues having bootstrap and prime NG css files in the same application?

bootstrap - http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/
Prime NG - https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup

Comment: there won't be an issue. But keeps in mind that if there are multiple classes with the same name, the last one will override those previous ones

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working on a project using both primeNG and bootstrap 3. I have absolutely no problem with them.

I am using Angular-CLI and I imported the required css files into the `scripts` attribute of the `angular-cli.json` file. But it's up to you to chose how to import them !

Comment: thanks for the update. But how did you refer it inside the angular-cli.json? I tried adding      "scripts": ["styles.css"], but that did not help?

Comment: Because 1 - Their style sheets aren't called style.css unless you changed them, 2 - it depends on how you installed it, if you used a CDN you can't import them in the angular cli file, 3 - Two libraries mean two files to import. You chose to import it in your CSS file, I've never done that so I can't help you, sorry !

Answer (score 1):

You can! :) But just be careful if you want to overide the bootstrap, put your code, after the @import :)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best primeng option is to use responsive tables, and also its layout and grades are like bootstrap. Only the class name is slightly different, for example, in bootstrap .col-12, but in primeng we write .p-col-12
I think check the primeng more and add bootstrap if necessary to prevent the code from getting heavy and cluttered.